# SQL Server Indexes based on another field

Tags: sql, indexing, azure-sql-database

Relatively new to SQL Server & Azure so have struggled to know what keywords I should be searching for this.

Basically I have a DB with fields UserID, & Journey_ID. Journey_ID value is constructed by User_ID_*autoincrementnumber*

How can I quickly build the journey_ID value such they come out in the format below? I could make a workaround for the max valeu when I cast the right of any characters after the underscore and into an integer, but there must be a better way?

Based on searching so far I've only struck up a clustered index based on User_ID - am I even close? Implementation of that is a whole other problem - but will investigate in more detail if that's the right direction.

```
USER_ID, Journey_ID

1, 1_1

1, 1_2

1, 1_3

2, 2_1

2, 2_2

3, 3_2
```

Comment: To get help finding the right solution you need to include more info on the end goal.  From what you posted I would say that you do not want to store the userid in the journeyid field.  It could be presented using a select statement such as : Select Convert(Varchar(10), User_Id) + '_' + Convert(Varchar(10), Journey_Id)

Comment: Essentially I just need an incremental field which is categorized by user. So there would be duplicates across users, but unique values by each user. Does that make sense?